# Login timeout disable?

Tags: login-screen, login

How can I disable automatic timeout entries in the login screen?  Allow me to explain.  My typical experience goes something like this: I put my laptop to sleep, then wake it.  When it wakes, it comes up with the login screen.  I type in my password and it will usually reject it, with a message indicating the login timer has expired.  I then enter my password a second time and it logs in.  Not the end of the world, but annoying nonetheless.  Any suggestions?

Comment: ['Related but doesn't look like quite the same' bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/50198)

Comment: Aha, that is it exactly! Looks like it's still an open issue. I'm still wondering though, can I just workaround it by disabling the automatic timeout somehow?

Comment: If you haven't already please go to the bug and click "this bug affects XX people, does this affect you" If, like me you can't contribute to bug reports for anything else, please contribute stats.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about the unlock screen, not the login screen?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're suffering from [bug #50198](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/50198). Please go to launchpad and click the 'this bug affects me' link to increase the urgency that the issue will get looked at.

There is a way to hack with pam to stop it asking for the password, but it's bad for security.